# Publicar pagina web wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Quiero publicar mi página web, ejemplo: mi web es misitio.com
pero si me meto en el navegador a mi sitio.com, me tira un error que no hay nada ahí, pero si me meto a misitio.com/wp aparece toda la información. Quiero saber como solucionar esto. Lo agradeciería bastante.
Saludos

Comment: Quizá te equivocaste al instalar Wordpress y lo pusiste dentro del directorio `wp`. Tenías que haberlo instalado en el directorio raíz, que suele ser `public_html`. Si el sitio es nuevo y no te interesa nada de lo que hay en el viejo, lo más simple es hacer una instalación nueva en el lugar correcto que es el directorio raíz. Si el sitio ya tiene contenido que te interesa, entonces debes moverlo de `wp` a `public_html`. Es un proceso fácil, pero hay que tomar unas precauciones [lee aquí](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/#moving-directories-on-your-existing-server)